# Objective-c EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x42)

Tags: objective-c, random, char, exc-bad-access

I'm new in Objective-C programmation and I receive this error when I run my little program (I just want to generate a random char). So here's what I've done so far:

```
(IBAction)generate{
  int a = arc4random() % 26;
  NSString * chaine = @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  char lettre = [chaine characterAtIndex:a];

  NSMutableString * mot = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCharacters:lettre length:1];
  hasard.text = mot;
}
```

I tried to simply put my variable 'lettre' in hasard.text but it won't work with the error 'Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to '`NSString *`' from '`char`'. So I created an `NSMutableString` to contain my character.

When I put the character "e" manually instead of the variable 'letter' on the fifth line it works well. Since I can see in the debugger that 'lettre' contains a random letter, why do I get the error in the title ?

`(EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x42))`.

Comment: You should prefer `arc4random_uniform(3)` to `arc4random(3)` with modulo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function is expecting a pointer to a character, you are giving it a literal character.  You need to create a pointer to it.  Also, `characterAtIndex` doesn't return a character as you would think.  It returns a *unicode character* which is actually an `unsigned short` instead of an `unsigned char`.  However, if you change your code to this it will work:

```
const unichar foo = [@"Test" characterAtIndex:0];
NSString *test = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&foo length:1]; //Note the &
```

**EDIT** But the simplest way would just be this:

```
char randChar = arc4random_uniform(26) + 'A'; //Changed in response to Jason Coco's comment
NSString *mot = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", randChar];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass something of the type `const unichar *`, not just `char`. You could do this instead:

```
- (IBAction)generate {
  int a = arc4random() % 26;
  NSString * chaine = @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  NSMutableString * mot = [chaine substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(a,1)];
  hasard.text = mot;
}
```

That way you just avoid the c string baloney altogether.

Answer (score 0):

For `[NSMutableString initWithCharacters:length:]`, it accepts a `C array of Unicode characters`, instead of `char` .

Actually you can substring your old string & use the string via `[NSMutableString initWithString]`.

Answer (score 0):

`initWithCharacters:length:` doesn't take a single character as its first argument. It takes an array of unichars (as a pointer of course). If you pass it a single character, it will try to dereference the character interpreted as a pointer, and it *will* segfault.

By the way, the approach you're taking for generating a one-letter substring is just way too complicated. We have the `sustringWithRange:` method, so use it:

```
- (IBAction)generate{
    int a = arc4random() % 26;
    NSString *chaine = @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    NSString *mot = [chaine substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(a, 1)];
    hasard.text = mot;
}
```

Also, even this method is overcomplicated. as @borrrden points out, simply use

```
(arc4random() % 26) + 'A'
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody still visits this question, one more useful thing to check is to make sure your not using ios6 specific code but in an ios5 simulator... This is what caused and solved the problem for me!